# resource binding is not working in laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I am using laravel 10 and building rest api. I am creating Categories resorce,controller, model

Route::apiResource('/admin-category', CategoryController::class);

this is the route in api.php.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreCategoryRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateCategoryRequest;
use App\Http\Resources\CategoryResource;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    /**
    * Display a listing of the resource.
    */
    public function index()
    {
        return Category::query()->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->paginate(10);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */
     public function store(StoreCategoryRequest $request)
     {
        $data = $request->validated();
        $data['image'] = $request['image'];
        $data['description'] = $request['description'];
        Category::create($data);
        return response(['success' => true, 'msg' => 'New Category created!'], 201);
     }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function show(Category $category)
    {
        // 
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update(UpdateCategoryRequest $request, Category $category)
    {
        $data = $request->validated();
        if(isset($request['image'])){
            $data['image'] = $request['image'];
        }
        $category->update($data);
        return response(['success' => true, 'msg' => 'Category updated!'], 200);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     */
    public function destroy(Category $category)
    {
        $category->delete();
        return response(['msg' => 'Deleted successfully', 'success' => true], 201);
    }
}
```

This is my controller and here index() and store method is working as well but destroy and update is not working and not showing any error.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
   use HasFactory;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array<int, string>
 */
  protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'image',
    'description'
  ];
}
```

This is Category model.

And migration is

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
};
```

I am trying from frontend. And category creating and fetch is working perfectly.

what is the problem with destroy and update?

I have checked many times payload is sending correctly with category id

Comment: because `admin-category` isn't `category` ... how is it supposed to match the route parameter `admin_category` to `category`? ... implicit binding needs the names to match

Comment: Thank you lagbox. Its working now if routing endpoint is just category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work for both update and destroy because you are not using the existing `Category` record. If you look at the route list, `update` will get `id` of existing `Category`. Same goes for `destroy` as well. So, I would change the followings:

For update:
From:

```php
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 */
public function update(UpdateCategoryRequest $request, Category $category)
{
    $data = $request->validated();
    if(isset($request['image'])){
        $data['image'] = $request['image'];
    }
    $category->update($data);
    return response(['success' => true, 'msg' => 'Category updated!'], 200);
}
```

To:

```php
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 */
public function update(UpdateCategoryRequest $request, string $id)
{
    $category = Category::find($id);
    $data = $request->validated();
    if(isset($request['image'])){
        $data['image'] = $request['image'];
    }
    $category->update($data);
    return response(['success' => true, 'msg' => 'Category updated!'], 200);
}
```

For destory:

From:

```php
/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 */
public function destroy(Category $category)
{
    $category->delete();
    return response(['msg' => 'Deleted successfully', 'success' => true], 201);
}
```

To:

```php
/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 */
public function destroy(string $id)
{
    $category = Category::find($id);
    $category->delete();
    return response(['msg' => 'Deleted successfully', 'success' => true], 201);
}
```